# Как получить переменную из функции другого модуля в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как из следующей функции, получить переменную login и password из другого модуля?

```
def logpass(message):
    logp = message.text.split(':')
    login = logp[0]
    password = logp[1]
```

Модуль в котором логин и пароль принимают значение называется bot.py, модуль в котором вызываются example.py
Приведите пример используя

```
print()
```

Не знаю подойдет ли return, так как функция не вызывается явно. Использую декораторы из telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def logpass(message):
```

Comment: `login = bot.login`?

Comment: @MaxU Не находит эту переменную, видимо из-за того, что она в функции

Comment: т.е. `logpass()` объявлена в `bot.py` ???

Comment: @MaxU именно....

Comment: если `login` и `password` определены __только__ в функции, то по-моему никак, а если они определены еще и вне функции, то `bot.login`

Comment: @MaxU есть ли какое нибудь решение для этого вопроса?

Comment: `logpass(message)` - это просто свободная функция или это метод класса?

Comment: @MaxU скорее свободная функция, но как я уже писал, она не вызывается явно

Comment: @MaxU может использовать list.append() ?? А сам список будет вне функции

Comment: в вашем вопросе недостаточно информации - что такое `message_handler`. Я специально скачал исходники "https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot", но не нашел там ни `message_handler` ни `logpass()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, это очень забавно, но похоже, таки можно:

```
code = bot.logpass.function_code
index = code.co_varnames.index('login')
value = code.co_consts(index + 1)
```

Без гарантий))

То есть в питоне ЕСТЬ теоретическая возможность получить значение ЛОКАЛЬНОЙ переменной функции ИЗВНЕ функции.

```
def f():
   x = 1
   y = 2

code = f.function_code
print (code.co_varnames) # -> ('x', 'y')
print (code.co_consts)   # -> (None, 1, 2)
```

Comment: вы можете привести полный пример? `function_code`, `co_varnames` - это атрибуты `inspect`?

Comment: @MaxU `function_code` - атрибут (насколько я понимаю) *любой* функции

Comment: хммм, в Python 3.5 - это не работает: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'function_code'`

Comment: @MaxU я игрался во 2-ом. За 3-й не скажу. Если честно, о существовании этого узнал ровно 5 минут назад)))

Comment: @MaxU в python3.x вместо `f.function_code` нужно писать `f.__code__`

Comment: спасибо! я этого не знал...